# C# Linq How to avoid Include and then include

Tags: c#, linq

I have an issue with a query on c#, The matter is that I have model with lots of navigation properties and execution time is very high

I have this situation

```
results = await _dbContext.Table0.Where(c =>
                                c.attribute == 23 &&
                               
                           .Include(c => c.table1)
                           .ThenInclude(g => g.table2)
                           .Include(c => c.table1)
                           .ThenInclude(g => g.table2).ThenInclude(l => l.table3).ThenInclude(m => m.table4)
                           .Include(c => c.table3)
                           .Include(c => c.table5)
                           .Include(c => c.table6
                           .Include(c => c.table7)
                           .ToListAsync();
```

but actually from all this tables I just need some attributes, not all the informations
Example from table1 i need 2 attributes, from table2 I need just one attribute, from table3 nothing but i need it to have some attributes of table 4 etc ..
How can I optimize this?

Comment: It is not clear what is collection navigation properties and what is just simple relation. To avoid retrieving unwanted fields, you can use `Select` and no Includes are needed. To make sample, answer what is collection and what is object and how final result should looks like.

Comment: I have some model with navigation properties with other models, Ex I have model 1 that is the representation of table 1 and in model 1 I have nav prop to model 2 which is the representation of table 2 and I need just some attributes of table 2

Comment: That's not what was asked. It's not clear if `c.table1` (etc.) is a collection or a reference. Anyway, as Svyatoslav says, you have to rewrite the query into something like `_dbContext.Table0.Where(...).Select(t => new CustomClass { ... }`, not using `Include`. `Include` always returns entire entities.

Comment: they are collections

Comment: Show final result. If they are collections, it means that you want to retrieve lists of lists, etc.

Comment: @user18363545 I think for now you've received enough suggestions to try and rewrite your query. Only you know which fields you want.

Comment: solved using SelectMany